# Retain Post title keywords in URL even if user changes post title or any other way to achieve SEO friendly permalink?

Tags: permalinks

I have one question and if you could advise, that would be grateful.

I have a WordPress website (not launched yet, testing phase). Registered users can submit post and comments. I am using 'Post name' as permalink structure. Issue arises when user changes the post title, the permalink also changes which from SEO point of view will have broken links in search if already indexed. I understand i can switch to 'Plain' permalink (Post Id) structure. But I want to utilize URL keywords from SEO point if view.

Is there any to achieve this by using custom permalink structure or only way is to use Plain permalink structure.

Answer (score 0):

In general only admins can change the post slug (effective the url), therefor as long as not everybody is an admin, the admin can go and change it without the author being able to modify it.

Same goes with the title tag, whatever SEO plugin you are using, make sure it lets only an admin to change the SEO related settings.